# why is my nested promise then returns undefined?

Tags: javascript, async-await

this is my code:

```
resolve: async (
        _root,
        { data: { password, interests, email, ...userData } },
        { prisma }
      ) => {
        console.log('called reg');
        const handleError = (error) => {
          console.log('error: ', error);
          return { token: null, error, userId: null };
        };
        return admin
          .auth()
          .createUser({
            email,
            password,
            displayName: `${userData.firstName} ${userData.lastName}`,
          })
          .then((userRecord) => {
            // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
            console.log('Successfully created new user:', userRecord);
            return admin
              .database()
              .ref('users/' + userRecord.uid)
              .set(
                {
                  ...userData,
                  interests,
                },
                (error) => {
                  if (error) return handleError(error);
                  else {
                    return admin
                      .auth()
                      .createCustomToken(userRecord.uid)
                      .then((token) => {
                        console.log('token: ', token)
                        return {
                          token,
                          error: null,
                          userId: userRecord.uid,
                        };
                      }, handleError);
                  }
                }
              );
          }, handleError)
          .then((result) => {
            console.log('result: ', result);
            return result;
          });
      },
```

I am using nested then in my graphql resolver, my question is, why is the result from last then returning  undefined? i cannot figure out since when i log inside the callback of createCustomToken, the token is there, so i was making sure to log the result at last then, but unfortunately, it's undefined, basically, i want to use .then and catch like this, not asyc/await, help?

Comment: May I know why do you prefer promises chaining over async/await?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use callback in the `set` method but chain a `then` to it. When you use callback, the `set` method will return `undefined` which is then assigned to `result` in the last `then` block. [Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#set)

Also, you don't have to provide the same `handleError` argument in every `then` method. You can replace them by chaining a `catch` method at the end.

```
...
return admin
  .database()
  .ref("users/" + userRecord.uid)
  .set({
    ...userData,
    interests,
  })
  .then(() => admin.auth().createCustomToken(userRecord.uid))
  .then((token) => {
    console.log("token: ", token);
    return {
      token,
      error: null,
      userId: userRecord.uid,
    };
  })
  .then((result) => {
    console.log("result: ", result);
    return result;
  }).catch(handleError);
```

In my opinion, *your code is very hard to read*. Writing more readable code will make the debugging process easier and generally, async/await can improve readability.

`async/await` version of your code:

```
async (
  _root,
  { data: { password, interests, email, ...userData } },
  { prisma }
) => {
  try {
    const userRecord = await admin.auth().createUser({
      email,
      password,
      displayName: `${userData.firstName} ${userData.lastName}`,
    });
    console.log("Successfully created new user:", userRecord);
    await admin
      .database()
      .ref("users/" + userRecord.uid)
      .set({
        ...userData,
        interests,
      });
    const token = await admin.auth().createCustomToken(userRecord.uid);
    console.log("token: ", token);
    return {
      token,
      error: null,
      userId: userRecord.uid,
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error: ", error);
    return { token: null, error, userId: null };
  }
};
```

Of course, readability is subjective. Pick a style that you and your teammates prefer.